# Trying to open jmx file in JMeter gives an error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I just downloaded Java and JMeter and when I try opening a .jmx file, I keep getting the following error message:

"Problem loading XML from:'C:\Users\blank\file_name.jmx'.
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: com.tag.jmeter.ext.config.PropertyReader"

I'm not sure what could be the issue. I installed the plugin manager and attempting to open the file after that did prompt me to install other required plugins I didn't have yet, but afterwards I still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I downloaded the "Property Reader" plugin separately and added that to my lib/ext folder. I guess the plugin manager missed that plugin.